# Operation not allowed when the object is closed in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to this site and also to VBA,
some how I managed to write VBA, but got above error. Please advise me any changes in my code. Thanks

```
Option Explicit
Const ConStrSql As String = "----"



Sub CopyDataFromDatabase()

Dim DataConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim StaffData As ADODB.Recordset
Dim DataFiels As ADODB.Field

Set DataConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set StaffData = New ADODB.Recordset

DataConn.ConnectionString = ConStrSql
DataConn.Open

On Error GoTo CloseConnection

With StaffData
.ActiveConnection = DataConn
.Source = "select ---"
.LockType = adLockReadOnly
.CursorType = adOpenKeyset

End With

On Error GoTo CloseRecordset

Worksheets.Add

For Each DataFiels In StaffData.Fields
ActiveCell.Value = DataFiels.Name
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Next DataFiels

Range("A1").Select
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset StaffData
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit

CloseRecordset:
StaffData.Close


CloseConnection:
DataConn.Close




End Sub
```

when I remove 
`CloseRecordset:
StaffData.Close`

I got columns listed in excel, but not data

Please any advise. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code defines `Recordset` but doesn't open it. Adding:

```
StaffData.Open
```

before:

```
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset StaffData
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks it resolved. can you please also suggest adding Stored Procedure in VBA. I think I nee that for later. Thanks

Comment: @KK1960 your question is unclear and not related to this problem. If you have any problems with stored procedures you should create a separate question and describe it with all the details.

Comment: @ user3964075, I got one more requirement in the same task. I got one column that contains values of Red, Amber, Green and N/A. Now I want background Color for according values (Red, Amber, Green and White). How can I do this in VBA? Thanks

Comment: @KK1960 I'd suggest to apply conditional formatting to this column - no need to check every single value. Otherwise you have to iterate through all rows, compare the value and set cells `.Interior.Color` accordingly.